# how link several pages, and adding a plugin to a new custom WordPress theme

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I've created my own WordPress custom theme for a website that I'm working on. It's my first time building  a theme from scratch! I'm having a difficulty 1st: to link several pages to the fron-page, or home page. For example lets say that I want to link "Who we are", page + "Contact us", page, etc.. How can I make WordPress understands that each page is different, and link to it? here is what I did so far:
in page.php I placed this code:

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="container">
<?php 
    if (have_post()) {
        while(have_post()) {
            the_post();
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page');
        }}
    ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer();  ?>
```

I also created a content-page.php where I've placed my HTML code. (I'm building the whole thing with an HTML and CSS code that's just like building a website from scratch).

I also want to know when using a plugin, how can I connect that into the pages that I'm adding. For example, if I'm installing a form such as WpForms for a page like "Contact us" how can I link that?
Please let me know if my questions need more details

Comment: Moodi, Re your other question:

> when using a plugin, how can I connect that into the pages that I'm
> adding.

please note wordpress theme standards say themes cannot include plugins, mustn’t add plugin functionalities, cannot require plugins to work.   However themes may recommend plugins from WordPress.org.

See https://make.wordpress.org/themes/handbook/review/required/#plugins

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly...
You want to be able to display (link) a couple of pages to your home page?
Ex:
[home page content here]
[Connect page content here] [Blurb page here]

If so, you need to pull in the page content into the home page.

Something like:

```
    <?php
$postid = 0 /*Need to get page id, that's the key */;

//Pull in the page data
$featured_page = get_post($postid);

$thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail( $featured_page->ID );

//Only show the excerpt in this case
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $featured_page->post_excerpt );

?>

<article id="post-<?php echo $featured_page->ID ?>">
    <header class="entry-header">
    <h1><?php echo $featured_page->post_title ?></h1>
    </header>
    <div class="entry-content">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <?php echo $thumbnail; ?>
    </div>
    <div>
      <?php echo $content; ?>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Important!  You'll need to get the page id from somewhere.  You can hard-code it in, but that's risky if something changes.  You can set up an Customizer option that lets the user select what page to use.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API

As for the contact form etc. I'd suggest putting it on a page as a shortcode, then displaying the full page, not the excerpt.

I use this code for a theme I built myself.  If you need anymore help, let me know, I can show you where to find it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm not quit sure it's working with me, but I keep trying